# Generic method, receive nullable value, return null or nonm-nullable value

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a `UserProfile` class containing many properties of generic type FieldDescription.
For filling the data I wrote a helper method `GetFieldDescriptionOrNull` which returns either null or the value itself. The data is not always existing so sometimes I want to pass a nullable value into function but get non-nullable value of it.
In my example I'm passing nullable int but want to either receive `FieldDescription<int>?` = null or if `user.UserData?.SearchArea` is not null just an instance of `FieldDescription<int>`. Is it possible?
Right now I'm getting compiler Error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'FieldDescription<int?>' to 'FieldDescription<int>'

public class FieldDescription<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public FieldDescription<int>? SearchArea { get; set; }
    //...
}

private FieldDescription<T>? GetFieldDescriptionOrNull<T>(T value)
{
   if (value == null)
      return null;

   return new FieldDescription<T> { Value = value };
}

profile.SearchArea = GetFieldDescriptionOrNull(user.UserData?.SearchArea);
```

Comment: `GetFieldDescriptionOrNull<T>(T? value)` although bear in mind that structs and classes work very differently when it comes to nullables. You might want to just add an `implicit` conversion operator on `FieldDescription` eg `public static implicit operator FieldDescription<T>(T value) => new(value);` then you can just do `profile.SearchArea = user.UserData?.SearchArea;`

Comment: You need discriminated unions :)